# TensorFlow 1.8 Cmake build with GPU fails on Windows 10 with a MSB6006 error

Tags: python, tensorflow, cmake

I'm attempting to compile TensorFlow on Windows 10 using the Cmake build (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/cmake). 
The build fails with the error: "error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" e
xited with code 1". (full error details below)

The build configuration is as follows:

- OS: Windows 10
- Python: 3.5.5 (Anaconda Python)
- Cmake: 3.11.3
- Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 (14.0.25431.01)
- CUDA 9.2, cuDNN 7.1
- GPU: Nvidia GeForce 940M
- TensorFlow 1.8 (Git tag v1.8.0)

Steps to reproduce:

```
git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow
cd tensorflow
git checkout v1.8.0
cd tensorflow\contrib\cmake
mkdir build
cd build

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat amd64

cmake .. -A x64 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ^
 -DSWIG_EXECUTABLE=C:/Dev_Tools/TFBuild/tools/swigwin-3.0.12/swig.exe ^
 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:/Users/UAMARTH/AppData/Local/Continuum/anaconda3/envs/tfbuild/python.exe ^
 -DPYTHON_LIBRARIES=C:/Users/UAMARTH/AppData/Local/Continuum/anaconda3/envs/tfbuild/libs/python35.lib ^
 -Dtensorflow_ENABLE_GPU=ON ^
 -Dtensorflow_CUDA_VERSION=9.2 ^
 -Dtensorflow_CUDNN_VERSION=7 ^
 -DCUDNN_HOME="C:\Dev_Tools\TFBuild\tools\cudnn-9.2-windows10-x64-v7.1" ^
 -Dtensorflow_WIN_CPU_SIMD_OPTIONS=/arch:AVX

MSBuild /p:Configuration=Release tf_python_build_pip_package.vcxproj
```

The cmake command complete without errors. The MSBuild command builds for about four hand half hours and then produces the following error:

```
"C:\Dev_Tools\TFBuild\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\tf_python_build_pip_package.vcxproj" (default target) (
1) ->
"C:\Dev_Tools\TFBuild\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\tf_python_api.vcxproj" (default target) (259) ->
(CustomBuild target) ->
  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(171,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" e
xited with code 1. [C:\Dev_Tools\TFBuild\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\tf_python_api.vcxproj]

    19591 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 04:30:49.38
```

Any ideas on the cause of the error and how to solve it?

Build instructions were taken from here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/cmake and here: http://www.python36.com/install-tensorflow-gpu-windows/

**Update 24/6/2018**

I did attempt to run the build using Python 3.6.
Initially it gave the following error,

```
"C:\Dev_Tools\TFBuild\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\tf_python_build_pip_package.vcxproj" (default target) (
1) ->
"C:\Dev_Tools\TFBuild\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\estimator_python_api.vcxproj" (default target) (2) ->
"C:\Dev_Tools\TFBuild\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.vcxproj" (default target) (3
) ->
"C:\Dev_Tools\TFBuild\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\pywrap_tensorflow_internal_static.vcxproj" (default tar
get) (4) ->
"C:\Dev_Tools\TFBuild\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\tf_c_python_api.vcxproj" (default target) (136) ->
(ClCompile target) ->
  C:\Dev_Tools\TFBuild\tensorflow\tensorflow\c\python_api.cc(19): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'tensorf
low/python/framework/cpp_shape_inference.pb.h': No such file or directory [C:\Dev_Tools\TFBuild\tensorflow\tensorflow\c
ontrib\cmake\build\tf_c_python_api.vcxproj]

    25406 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 04:40:36.11
```

I read about the 'cpp_shape_inference.pb.h' error here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/18931 and attempted the fix suggested there. However, the suggested fix resulted in the following error,

```
"C:\Dev_Tools\TFBuild\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\tf_python_build_pip_package.vcxproj" (default target) (
1) ->
"C:\Dev_Tools\TFBuild\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\estimator_python_api.vcxproj" (default target) (2) ->
(CustomBuild target) ->
  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(171,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" e
xited with code 1. [C:\Dev_Tools\TFBuild\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\estimator_python_api.vcxproj]


"C:\Dev_Tools\TFBuild\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\tf_python_build_pip_package.vcxproj" (default target) (
1) ->
"C:\Dev_Tools\TFBuild\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\tf_python_api.vcxproj" (default target) (264) ->
  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(171,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" e
xited with code 1. [C:\Dev_Tools\TFBuild\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\tf_python_api.vcxproj]

    25792 Warning(s)
    2 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 04:47:42.89
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: I believe for tensorflow 1.7 and above the compatible python versions are python3.6 and Cuda 9.0 and you need cudNN 7.0, I use them with out the cmake, and it works for me

Comment: I will attempt building with Python 3.6. But I need the CUDA 9.2 and 7.1 support, as it's the main reason I'm trying to compile from source myself :)

Comment: I attempted the build with Python 3.6, but that also failed. I've updated the question with the latest errors I got when using Python 3.6